# C# Access a static method that is hidden by a local property

Tags: c#

I'm sure this must have been asked already, but I can't seem to find the answer. I need to know how to access a static method, when the class it is defined within has been hidden by an instance method with the same name.

I have a class which exposes a static method as follows:

```
public class Plan
{
    public static Plan Generate(Project project)
    {
        var plan = new Plan();
        // ... 
        return plan;
    }
}
```

I then have another class which contains a method called "Plan", from which I want to call the static method mentioned above:

```
public ActionResult Plan(int id)
{
    // ...
    var plan = Plan.Generate(project);
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the class name 'Plan' is hidden by the method name, so I cannot call the static method directly.

Comment: `YourNamespace.Plan.Generate`. That said, static methods are bad mkay. Make yourself an `IPlanFactory`, bind `PlanFactory` to it and let dependency injection do the rest (assuming you're using constructor injection and not that hairbrained dependency resolver stuff). Now it's unambigiously `_planFactory.Generate(...)` and you've just increased testability. Give yourself a raise!

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualify your access to the `Plan` type with the type's name. For example:

```
YourNamespace.Plan.Generate
```

<sub>That said, static methods are bad mkay. Make yourself an `IPlanFactory`, bind `PlanFactory` to it and let dependency injection do the rest (assuming you're using constructor injection and not that hairbrained dependency resolver stuff). Now it's unambigiously `_planFactory.Generate(...)` and you've just increased testability. Give yourself a raise!</sub>